# Why don't I have a quest arrow for Shalidor's Insights?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[**Urag gro-Shub**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Urag_gro-Shub) wants me to find the **Shalidor's Insights** book for the Shalidor's Insights quest.

But my quest arrow doesn't point anywhere. I don't have a quest arrow that shows me where to go. Why could that be?

Answer (score 3):

Shalidor's Insight is found at a radiant location. At least one possible location is on Solstheim, the island that is added with Dragonborn DLC, and which can only be accessed by a boat that docks near Windhelm. If the quest marker is nowhere on the Skyrim world map, check Solstheim.

There is a long list of possible locations. The [**wiki**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Shalidor%27s_Insights_(Book)) page gives information on the book and links to ALL possible locations.

Good luck finding your book!

Comment: I would like to notify the original author of the answer to review the current edit as i believe the attempt to "merge answers" by Finn Rayment deviates from the original meaning of the answer and also make it now much harder to read having to scroll an entire page to get to the end

Comment: @Memor-X Thanks for the note. Printing the full list in an answer seems a bit ridiculous to me too. If anybody cares for the whole list, they can check the wiki for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when i go to ( show on map ) . The map wont work in locating it with the map marker at times. 
So i back out and leave the quest checked ..... then go to the map on my own .
I have found its there , but wasnt releasing through the quest ( show on map ) function.

Try that !